# How to update Drawer instance of react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

We are using startSingleScreenApp to start the application. We need to hide/show some of the menu option based on screen in the application.

We tried to create two different Drawer with different items but in that case drawer items not getting rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom component for your drawerMenu instead of default provided menu styling and properties. Create a custom component, and for the menu items, map through an array of menu items provided by redux. Then whenever you need to change the menu items, change the array state in redux and your drawer menu items will re-render and update accordingly.